# Boost Threadpool with network or GPU

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm using a thread group like shown here [Boost group_threads Maximal number of parallel thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685176/boost-group-threads-maximal-number-of-parallel-thread)

My program does depth graph search which takes really long. Because that i want to speed up. I thought about connection other Computers over network or using my GPU.

So it is possible to start threads on other computers over network(of course they have to run client) or to use the own GPU

Does boost thread support something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boost thread does not support this exactly.  Boost threads are specific to a given process.

For the multi-machine case, you would need to communicate between the machines over the network.  You could use boost asio sockets or boost MPI for this.

For the GPU case, you would have to write code specifically to execute on the GPU which is an in-depth subject.

You could also take a look at OpenCL which may be a better fit for your purpose.