# Difference between Boost Thread and thread_group

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I wanted to know what the difference between a boost::thread and a boost::thread_group is the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup) states.

> thread_group provides for a collection of threads that are related in
>   some fashion. New threads can be added to the group with add_thread
>   and create_thread member functions. thread_group is not copyable or
>   movable.

Apart from thread categorization I am not sure what other differences there might be and when should I prefer to use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

A thread groups is... a *group* of threads.

You should use it whenever you want to manage a group of threads that logically share a purpose, lifetime etc.

E.g. when writing a task queue with a pool of worker threads¹, the construction of the threads and destruction thereof isn't trivial with

- exception safety
- joining joinable threads in all code paths

So you'd use a `thread_group` to get all this machinery automatically.

---

¹ see here for an example: [Boost group_threads Maximal number of parallel thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685176/boost-group-threads-maximal-number-of-parallel-thread/22688890#22688890)