# Use boost phoenix lambda with io_service

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, boost-phoenix

I am using boost io_service to run methods asynchronously:

```
void my_class::completion_handler()
{
  ...
}
m_io_service.post(boost::bind(&my_class::completion_handler, this));
```

I would like to use lambda expression instead of boost::bind (see below) in order to avoid creating method for each handler but I am using a C++ compiler that does not support C++11 fully:

```
m_io_service.post([this](){ ... });
```

Is it possible to have the same behavior by using phoenix lambda ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's possible.

Most notable difference is the placeholders (don't use `std::place_holders::_1`, `_2`... but `boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1`, `arg2`...).

However, simply replacing `boost::bind` with `std::bind`, `boost::lambda::bind` or `boost::phoenix::bind` is ultimately useless of course.

Instead you could use Phoenix actors to compose "lambdas", like e.g.

```
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

boost::mutex mx;
boost::condition_variable cv;
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lk(mx);
vc.wait(lk, phx::ref(m_queue_size) > 0);
```

Member invocations are tricky in that respect.

The good news is that Phoenix comes with implementations of many STL operations like `size()`, `empty()`, `push_back()` etc.

Similar use of Phoenix in this queue implementation: [Boost group_threads Maximal number of parallel thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685176/boost-group-threads-maximal-number-of-parallel-thread) and e.g. [asio::io_service and thread_group lifecycle issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304286/asioio-service-and-thread-group-lifecycle-issue/34306588#34306588)).

### `boost::fusion::function<>`

You can adapt free functions with `BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION` and function objects with `BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_CALLABLE`. However in the latter case it's probably more elegant to use `boost::fusion::function<>`:

```
struct MyType {
    MyType()
        : complete_(complete_f { this }) 
    { }

    void doSomething() { }

   private:    
     struct complete_f {
         MyType* _this;
         void operator()() const {
             // do something with _this, e.g
             this->doSomething();
         }
     };

     boost::phoenix::function<complete_f> complete_;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So is it not possible to make easier by using phoenix::lambda directly ? Like this
`m_io_service.post(phoenix::lambda(local-declarations)
[
    lambda-body
]);`

Comment: Nope. There's http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/operator.html#phoenix.modules.operator.member_pointer_operator but it doesn't eexactly make things easier IYAM

Comment: And, no, lambda is just a way to make a named actor with potentially multiple statements. But you'll still have to awkwardly bind the member function invocation (because C++ doesn't have transparent proxy types and/or `operator.`)